Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'options') when attempting to install angular data-tables
I am in the process of updating my Angular app from v14 to v17. One step I am taking while doing this is to upgrade angular-datatables. Upon running ng add angular-datatables I get an error related to undefined options. Here is the full terminal log:
PS C:\Users\IM010907\Documents\git\Dashboard\ID_Client> npm run add-datatables

> icm@1.0.0 add-datatables
> ng add angular-datatables

? Would you like to share pseudonymous usage data about this project with the Angular Team
at Google under Google's Privacy Policy at https://policies.google.com/privacy. For more  
details and how to change this setting, see https://angular.io/analytics. No
Global setting: not set
Local setting: disabled
Effective status: disabled
ℹ Using package manager: npm
✔ Found compatible package version: angular-datatables@17.0.0.
✔ Package information loaded.

The package angular-datatables@17.0.0 will be installed and executed.
Would you like to proceed? Yes
✔ Packages successfully installed.
? Which styling library would you like to use for DataTables? Bootstrap 5
    Your project needs Bootstrap CSS installed and configured for changes to take affect.
    ℹ️  Skipped adding "jquery" into package.json
    ✅️ Added "datatables.net" into "dependencies"
    ✅️ Added "@types/jquery" into "devDependencies"
    ✅️ Added "datatables.net-bs5" into "dependencies"
     Installing packages...
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'options')

I have tried...

installing with default styling and Bootstrap 5.
using the manual installation as shown on their docs
deleting my node_modules / package.json before running the command.
removing any old scripts / styles from angular.json

Thanks in advance for any possible tips!

if there's a github I would report it there

The schematic seems to try to update you angular.json to add some asset. The problem is this line:   const targetLocation: string[] = targets.build.options[assetType]; ... build is not defined. Please check there schematic but it seems it is not valid:
https://github.com/l-lin/angular-datatables/blob/705f26c7291fac5a102d6acc6e665195d47ed809/schematics/src/ng-add/utils/index.ts
The issue could be if you are using "nx" or such other tools. In this case the angular.json is not as expected.

I am using nx and recently updated that as well. What would nx do that is related / why would that be the issue / do you have any idea where I can look to attempt to fix that?

Issue / Cause
The issue is that the schematic is unable to add an asset to the angular.json because the project it is trying to access has no build options.
Upon looking through their source code I found the following function (Thanks to Thomas Renger for the link):
export function addAssetToAngularJson(host: Tree, assetType: string, assetPath: string): boolean {
  /* tslint:disable-next-line: no-non-null-assertion */
  const sourceText = host.read('angular.json')!.toString('utf-8');
  const json = JSON.parse(sourceText);

  if (!json) return false;

  const projectName = Object.keys(json['projects'])[0];
  const projectObject = json.projects[projectName];
  const targets = projectObject.targets || projectObject.architect;

  const targetLocation: string[] = targets.build.options[assetType];

  // update UI that `assetPath` wasn't re-added to angular.json
  if (targetLocation.indexOf(assetPath) != -1) return false;

  targetLocation.push(assetPath);

  host.overwrite('angular.json', JSON.stringify(json, null, 2));

  return true;

}

I realized that they are just assuming that I want the settings from the first project. My angular.json was automatically sorted alphabetically (possibly from NX or some other tool). Because of this, it was attempting to access a project that only required lint / test configuration settings. My project looked somewhat similar to the following:
"projects": {
   "project_a": {
       "architect": {
           "lint": {
               "options": {
                  // Options here
               }
           },
           "test": {
               "options": {
                  // Options here
               }
           }
       }
   },
   "project_b": {
       "architect": {
           "lint": {
               "options": {
                  // Options here
               }
           },
           "test": {
               "options": {
                  // Options here
               }
           },
           "build": { // THIS IS THE SECTION THAT MUST BE IN THE PROJECT AT INDEX 0
               "options": {
                  // Options here
               }
           }
       }
   },
   "project_c": {
       "architect": {
           "lint": {
               "options": {
                  // Options here
               }
           },
           "test": {
               "options": {
                  // Options here
               }
           }
       }
   }
}

Solution / TLDR
All you have to do to fix this is move the project that has build settings up to the top and this will fix the problem as there will now be build settings to read at index 0. I was able to run ng add angular-datatables with no issues after this.
"projects": {
   "project_b": {
       "architect": {
           "lint": {
               "options": {
                  // Options here
               }
           },
           "test": {
               "options": {
                  // Options here
               }
           },
           "build": { // THIS IS THE SECTION THAT MUST BE IN THE PROJECT AT INDEX 0
               "options": {
                  // Options here
               }
           }
       }
   },
   "project_a": {
       "architect": {
           "lint": {
               "options": {
                  // Options here
               }
           },
           "test": {
               "options": {
                  // Options here
               }
           }
       }
   },
   "project_c": {
       "architect": {
           "lint": {
               "options": {
                  // Options here
               }
           },
           "test": {
               "options": {
                  // Options here
               }
           }
       }
   }
}

